# How to read an input file in java

Tags: java

Input file:

```
1/2/3/5/6
```

I want to store numbers `1 2 3 4 5 6`

My code:

```
Scanner in= new Scanner(new FileReader("v.txt"));
in.split();
```

Is not there so how can I store these values?

Comment: U would have googled it before asking the question!!!

Comment: @user4192725 hope my answer helps you

Comment: I see a lot of questions of this nature, where the OP asks a basic question and then disappears.

Comment: Why is this not getting downvoted into roomba territory?

Comment: @Madusudanan ya I totally agree with you. They do not appreciate the help they get.

Comment: @JamesMassey I do not know may be everybody is sleeping lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**. There is a **coolest trick** about `Scanner` that you can read the whole file into a string.

```
String text = new Scanner(new FileReader("v.txt")).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

[Source for Scanner Tricks](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/pat/archive/2004/10/stupid_scanner.html)

**2**. you can split the string by using `/` delimiters

**3**. you can go through the String one by one an convert each `String` to `Integer` number.

```
  a. Integer.valueOf() which return Integer 
  b. Integer.parseInt() which return int
```

In `Java 8`

Code:

```
    String text = new Scanner(new FileReader("1.txt")).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    String[] sp = text.split("/");
    List<Integer>  listIntegers = Stream.of(sp)
                                        .map( s -> Integer.valueOf(s))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    listIntegers.forEach(i -> System.out.print(" " + i));
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Needed Imports:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
```

Comment: @user4192725 one little mistake. valueOf return Integer and parseInt return int see my update

Answer (score 1):

First read the full line of text.

```
String line="";
while(in.hasNextLine(){
 line=in.nextLine();
}
```

Then split the line by `/`

```
String[] arr=line.split("/");
```

If you want to get these as `int` values, you can use `Integer.parseInt()` to get `int` from `String`.

Answer (score 1):

if you use Java 7:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path to file"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: That is only half the way asked.

Answer (score 0):

try followind code:

```
Scanner in= new Scanner(new FileReader("v.txt"));
String tok[];
while(in.hasNextLine(){
 tok=in.nextLine().spilt("/");
}
```

**Input :**

```
1/2/3/5/6
```

**Output :**

```
1
2
3
5
6
```

For more on such operations visit [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) link.

Comment: Unnecessary escaping. You can use `split("/")` without escaping.